# Qt 3D Studio Animating only one element in a slide, while keeping other elements stay where they are

Tags: qt, qt3d

I am working on a project with Qt 3D Studio, I have a concern regarding animating single objects in slide, while rest of the objects are not effected.

[image]

To explain, let's consider three Slides "MoveCarRight", "MoveCarCenter" and "SignNoRight". (Please see attached picture to give you idea about my scene.)
"MoveCarRight" is used for moving car to right, "SignNoRight" is used for animating traffic sign on the Z axis so that it enters the scene.
I control those slides from QML side by entering:

```
presentation.goToSlide("Scene","MoveCarRight")

presentation.goToSlide("Scene","SignNoRight")
```

However, inevitably I can't control the objects seperately. When I go to slide "SignNoRight", I want the car to stay the same, if it was previously moved to center, it should stay at the center, if it was previously moved to right, it should stay right. Right now, when I enter "SignNoRight" it is always centered.

I would think there would be a simple solution to this, yet I couldn't find it. Any help is greately appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem with the introduction of data input controllers. See example: https://doc.qt.io/qt3dstudio/openglruntime/qtstudio3d-qmldatainput-qml-qmldatainput-main-qml.html